# Prometheus monitoring for Apache Ignite via JMX

Tags: java, prometheus, jmx, ignite

I'm trying to monitor Apache Ignite with Prometheus' JMX exporter, but I'm seeing only default JVM metrics plus metrics only for "Thread Pools" Beans.
JMX exporter run as agent:

```
/usr/bin/java -XX:+AggressiveOpts -javaagent:/etc/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.13.0.jar=8080:/etc/prometheus/prometheus_config.yml -Xms1g -Xmx1g -server -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=49112 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -DIGNITE_QUIET=true -DIGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=/usr/share/apache-ignite/work/ignite_success_ed3b2798-4d48-4188-94ac-1728fa8628dc -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49112 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DIGNITE_HOME=/usr/share/apache-ignite -DIGNITE_PROG_NAME=/usr/share/apache-ignite/bin/ignite.sh -cp /usr/share/apache-ignite/libs/*:/usr/share/apache-ignite/libs/ignite-indexing/*:/usr/share/apache-ignite/libs/ignite-spring/*:/usr/share/apache-ignite/libs/licenses/* org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup /etc/apache-ignite/default-config.xml
```

Ignite config has enables metrics:

```
<property name="metricExporterSpi">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.metric.jmx.JmxMetricExporterSpi"/>
    </list>
</property>
```

I can see a lot of ignite metrics from jconsole connected to 49112 port.
[image: jconsole]

Tried different jmx-exporter options, nothing helped.

```
---
hostPort: 127.0.0.1:49112
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
lowercaseOutputName: true
```

```
---
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
lowercaseOutputName: true
rules:
- pattern: "^org.apache<clsLdr=(.+), name=sys"
  name: ignite_sys_stats
  help: Ignite cluster amount of heap memory in bytes
  labels:
    attr: $3
  type: GAUGE
```

and even empty config, that should mean "gather everything as is", still see just standard JVM + "Thread Pools".
Can you suggest what's wrong here ?

Comment: Since JConsole can consume all the metrics from the exporter, it sounds like the issue is on the JMX Prometheus exporter end. It might be that the Prometheus exporter can't parse messages of the Ignite exporter SPI. Do you use this exporter?  https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

Comment: It seems I faces with https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/issues/483


`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport cannot be cast to javax.management.Attribute
 at io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.scrapeBean(JmxScraper.java:160)
 at io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.doScrape(JmxScraper.java:117)
 at io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.main(JmxScraper.java:329)`
when I run io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to use Prometheus OpenCensus export. Ignite can export metrics in that format: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/new-metrics#opencensus

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an empty prometheus_config.yml file. Make sure the file is properly read.
   Trace here: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/ce04b7dca8615d724d8f447fa25c44ae1c29238b/collector/src/main/java/io/prometheus/jmx/JmxCollector.java#L75
   to make sure you are using the correct file.
2. remove the metricExporterSpi property
3. connect to the port specified, 8080 in your case, to see all the results.

Your pattern matching rules are not allowing Apache Ignite results to show properly.

You can use debug/tracing instructions here: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter
to see what is happening.

pattern rule processing is here: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/ce04b7dca8615d724d8f447fa25c44ae1c29238b/collector/src/main/java/io/prometheus/jmx/JmxCollector.java#L357

Comment: I added catching ClassCastException for JmxScrapper.javs now java -cp collector/target/collector*.jar  io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:49112/jmxrmi returns more then 800 items, but when I run javaagent - it gives me only 64 items

Comment: The javaAgent most likely returns only the JVM properties. It might be an error in the javaagent.

Comment: Yep, jmx was not catching ClassCastException. I added catch and now I see metrics (some skipped due to "TabularDataSupport cannot be cast to javax.management.Attribute", but now it's just ignoring these metrics instead of failing.